# After Promise object not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been trying to display map an array after resolving its promise. Unfortunately, it is not being rendered. Here is the code:

```
<View>
     {array.map((item) => {
        promiseFunction(item).then((res) => {
          return (
            <FunctionalComponent
             prop={res.prop}
            />
          );
        });
      })}
</View>
```

Comment: Your map callback doesn't return anything. And if it _did_, it would be a promise. You can't render a value you don't have yet.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @jonrsharpe
Edit: what if the value comes non-immediately but after a small delay. setTimeout doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map() won't wait for Promise to resolve, so data will never be rendered. You should try classic for ... of.

```
const Foo = ({}) => {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      for (const item of array) {
        setComponents([...conponents, <FunctionalComponent prop={(await promiseFunction(item)).prop}/>])
      }
    })()
  }

  return (
   <View>
     {components}
   </View> 
  )
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Unexpected reserved word await" for the retrieving a prop value.

Comment: @LakshyaMonga, I corrected the code, it should work

Comment: I'll check it out, sure

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the async function from rendering. And you have to do the `array.map` properly. The list of FunctionalComponent props must be a state.

```
const [propsArray, setPropsArray] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {    // or any other function, that will feed data
    array.map(item => {
         promiseFunction(item).then(res => {
                setPropsArray(p => [...p, res])
         }
    }, 
[])

return (<View>
 {propsArray.map(c => (<FunctionalComponent prop={c.prop} />) }
</View>)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Fide. Have a good day

Comment: I think you should do:  `Promise.all(array.map(item => {
         promiseFunction(item)
    }).then(props => setProps(props))`  
Not sure how react will batch those rerenders in your example.

Comment: Tried it, worked better than the previous + learnt a new method. Truly grateful. ❤❤

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly as you are trying to since React will try to render an array of promises and when they have resolved it's too late the Component has already rendered. Previous answers showd you how to set to state the results once they come and render only after the promises are fulfilled.  But with React@18 you could jump that step and render the *promises* almost directly.
If you are using Suspense, there is a way to handle this kind of scenarios, because *Suspended* components are able to consume promises directly and to render a fallback until they resolve:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading.....</p>}>
      <AsyncComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export const AsyncComponent = () => {
  // THIS IS AN ARRAY OF PROMISES

  const data = arr.map((el, i) => {
    const d = useGetData(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i + 1}`);
    console.log(d);
    return (
      <h5>
        {i + 1}:{d?.title}
      </h5>
    );
  });
  // HERE YOU RENDER THE PROMISES DIRECTLY
  return <div>{data}</div>;
};
```

A demo that you can play with, [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rxzwvd?file=src%2FApp.js).